# Can I have configuration specific resources in XCode

Tags: xcode

I have an Xcode iPhone project with 3 configurations, debug, release and adhoc.  What I need to do is include a resource file only for the debug builds, and not for the others.  Can anyone tell me how to do this please?

I know I can have different project settings and preprocessor directives per configuration, and different resource files per target, but I need to only have one target.

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it's possible without creating a second (or third) target, and putting config-specific resources in its Copy Bundle Resources step.

Alternatively, you could copy all resources in your existing target, and then use a post-build step to selectively delete unrelated resources, but you'll incur some overhead, and it's not exactly an elegant solution.